# Does OCaml do immutable data structure sharing?

Tags: ocaml

Does OCaml do structural sharing of immutable data structure by default ([link](https://raganwald.com/2019/01/14/structural-sharing-and-copy-on-write.html))?

If not, is there something like an constructor attribute that specifies when to share instances?

Comment: No, if you want hash-consing, you have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semantics of immutable data are such that you can't tell whether it is being shared or not. So it's not really possible to make strong claims along these lines (IMHO). Different implementations could do things differently, and things could be different at different places in your code.

However, OCaml does the obvious thing when applying functions (i.e., passing parameters) and when moving vaues (via `let` or reference assignment). In other words, yes OCaml shares structures when a value is moved around.

However there is no special work to detect identical values and coalesce them. So if you have:

```
let x = (1, 2, 3) in
let y = (1, 2, 3) in
...
```

There is no guarantee that the values of `x` and `y` are shared. In fact (in the implementations I'm aware of), they won't be.

If you want the data to be shared in this case you can write:

```
let x = (1, 2, 3) in
let y = x in
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have sharing of immutable data structures in OCaml.
This can be done through a feature called *functional update* which is described [here](https://ocamlbook.org/records-and-references/#immutable-records-and-functional-updates)

Using the with clause of records, you can specify which fields of a record you want to have shared.

Consider the following example:

```
type t = {a: string; b: string}

let x = {a= "a"; b= "b"}

let y = {a= "a"; b= "b"}

let () = Format.print_bool (x.a == y.a) (* prints false *)

let () = Format.print_bool (x.b == y.b) (* prints false *)
```

Here, we have two structurally equal records, but as you can see, their fields are physically different, *ie* not share.

Now we can build `y` built by sharing the fields of `x`, except for the field `b` for example:

```
let y = {x with b= "b"}

let () = Format.print_bool (x.a == y.a) (* prints true *)

let () = Format.print_bool (x.b == y.b)
(* prints false as only the field a was shared *)
```

The memory representation of records consist more or less in a list of pointers to their fields. This operation copies the pointers, rather than the values directly, and hence the sharing.

Comment: That's the same as `y = {a= x.a, b= "b"}`, right?

Comment: Yes. The syntactic shorthand pays off the more fields you have and are not updating.

Comment: Another example would be constructing a list from the tail of another list. `List.(let x = [1;2;3] in let y = 0 :: tl x in tl x == tl y)`